# Accessing functions from an external .js file

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, camera

This is my external .js file from my HTML.

HTML: li id="getPhoto"

What's the best way to access this function. Can't get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#getPhoto').click(function() {
      function getPhoto(source) {
         // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source });
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything happening here. When you click #getPhoto, you're just declaring the `getPhoto()` function, not calling it. This is how you would call the function.

```
$('#getPhoto').click(function() {
   getPhoto(someVar);
});

function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { 
       quality: 50, 
       destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
       sourceType: source 
    });
}
```

That should set you on the right path.. But it looks like you might be in over your head.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was kind of thinking this but wasn't sure. Going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are just declaring the function on click. If you remove a few lines, you could use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#getPhoto').click(function() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: source });
 });
});
```

You wouldn't be passing the source variable in, so you'd need to find some other way to get it into the function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'll have to try this.